# How to split with Python a LaTeX file between math and text environments

Tags: python-3.x, latex, python-re

In order to make further transformation solely over the text parts, I want to split a latex file regarding the nature of the environment : for example, if I have :

```
latex_text = """A latex example
$$ \int = 0$$
with different
\[\sum \] 
\[\sum \]
math delimiters $\\cos(x)$.
"""
```

I would like to obtain something like this :

```
["A latex example","$$ \int = 0$$","with different","\[\sum \]", "\[\sum \]","math delimiters","$\\cos(x)$","."]
```

With `re.split(r'([\\][[]|[\\][]]|[$][$]|[$])',latex_text)`, I have

```
['A latex example\n', '$$', ' \\int = 0', '$$', '\nwith different\n', '\\[', '\\sum ', '\\]', ' \n', '\\[', '\\sum ', '\\]', '\nmath delimiters ', '$', '\\cos(x)', '$', '.\n']
```

Which is a start, but I need to re-attach the latex math delimiters : I was wondering if it was possible to let them in from the start ?

Comment: off-topic: don't use `$$...$$` for math in latex.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, you are right, but I have to work with various already existing files...

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with the code :

```
res_prem = re.split(r'([\\][[]|[\\][]]|[$][$]|[$])',latex_text)


delim = {r'\[',r'$$',r'$'}

res = []
i = 0
while i < len(res_prem):
    u = res_prem[i]
    if u in delim:
        compact = res_prem[i] + res_prem[i+1] + res_prem[i+2]
        res.append(compact)
        i = i + 3
    else:
        res.append(u)
        i += 1
```

Not sure that it is really pythonic, so any improvement is welcome !